# Function that calculates diffrent positions from an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, math

I have a problem that I need help solving. Im supposed to create a function that calculates the distance between two positions. The positions are stored in two arrays, I can use as many parameters that I need to do this calculation

```
static double[] Latitudes = new double[] { 
  59.3261917, 57.7010496, 59.8939529, 65.5867395, 60.11021, 52.5069312, 48.859 
};

static double[] Longitudes = new double[] { 
  17.7018773, 11.6136602, 10.6450348, 22.0422998, 24.7385057, 13.1445521, 2.2069765 
};
```

I have been given an equation that will help me calculate the distance

```
distance = Math.sqrt( (x1 - x2)2 + (y1 - y2)2  )
```

My problem is that I can't get the elements from the arrays to the variables inside the function

Comment: why? what have you tried?

Comment: Which ones do you want to calculate? Every two pairs or specific ones?

Comment: @FCin It's supposed to be specific ones, so Latitudes[0] are linked up with Longitudes[0]

Comment: `Latitudes[0]` is `y1` and `Longitudes[0]` is `x1`. So where's the problem? You want to find distance between element `0` and `3` then pass to function these variables.

Comment: do you know how to use a for-loop ? You comment shows that you know how to access items in an array at specific indices

Comment: I note that your computation of the Euclidean distance is *wrong* if the points are latitude and longitude. The Euclidean distance only works on a flat grid of equal sized squares. The grid given by latitude and longitude is not flat -- it's wrapped around a sphere -- and the squares are not of equal size -- a one-degree square near the pole is smaller than a one-degree square near the equator.   You need to use spherical trigonometry to work out the great-circle distance between two points on the surface of the earth.

Comment: Yeah a friend of mine solved it, thanks for all the awnsers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show distance for all pairs

```
if (Latitudes.Length == Longitudes.Length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Latitudes.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
    {
        double x1 = Longitudes[i];
        double x2 = Longitudes[i + 1];
        double y1 = Latitudes[i];
        double y2 = Latitudes[i + 1];
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.Pow(y1 - y2, 2));

        Console.WriteLine($"x1 = {x1}; x2 = {x2}; y1 = {y1}; y2 = {y2}; distance {distance}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well first you need to decide which positions you want to compare. This would be done by index. Lets says you want to compare positions at index `0` with positions at index `2`. Then the code to get the correct variables would be:

```
double x1 = Latitudes[0];
double y1 = Longitudes[0];
double x2 = Latitudes[2];
double y2 = Longitudes[2];
```

You can then feed those values into your function. Your function code is wrong and won't compile. The correct call for the function would be:

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.Pow(y1 - y2, 2));
```

---

In the interest of providing a more complete function for your class, and keeping in mind that your arrays are static, this will allow you to get the distance from any two given points based on index. Also, I expect this is a homework assignment so I am leaning towards your requirement to be creating a function similar to this:

```
double CalculateDistance(int index1, int index2)
{
    double x1 = Latitudes[index1];
    double y1 = Longitudes[index1];
    double x2 = Latitudes[index2];
    double y2 = Longitudes[index2];

    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.Pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
```

You can then call this function as follows:

```
double distance = CalculateDistance(0, 2);
```

Comment: that's something very basic ... not complaining about your answer but I won't post an answer for

Comment: @Rahul: You are right, it is basic, but it's a valid question. Perhaps there is a duplicate and maybe that should have be the correct course of action, but I like that the OP has shown some code and asked a clear question. It's a welcomed rarity for such low rep users.

Comment: I think this answers the question too. though I am not sure OP will get it to use easily .

Comment: @Pac0: Think again ;) haha

Answer (score 2):

*Extract methods*, split you problem into *minor* ones:

```
 // Initial step:
 // Distance between points
 private static double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
   return Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)); 
 }

 // Next step: 
 // Distance between points given as arrays' items indexes
 private static double Distance(double[] xs, double[] ys, int indexFrom, indexTo) {
   return Distance(xs[indexFrom], ys[indexFrom], xs[indexTo], ys[indexTo]);
 }
```

Then use

```
 // What is the distance between 0-th and 2-nd point?
 double result = Distance(Latitudes, Longitudes, 0, 2);

 Console.WriteLine(result);

 // What is the distance between all the points?
 for (int from = 0; from < Math.Min(Latitudes.Length, Longitudes.Length); ++from) 
   for (int to = from + 1; to < Math.Min(Latitudes.Length, Longitudes.Length); ++to) {
     Console.WriteLine($"Distance from item #{from} to item #{to} is {Distance(Latitudes, Longitudes, from, to)}");
   }
```

Comment: I think this is probably a bit OTT for this question and will only add to the OP's confusion (it's clear they are on a basic level here), but it is correct and it would also be my personal preference to separate the logic out into short functions